# Is there a way to bail from a bats test?

Tags: bats-core

Is there a way to bail out of an entire test file? the entire test suite?

Something along the lines of

```
@test 'dependent pgm unzip' {
  command -v unzip || BAIL 'missing dependency unzip, bailing out'
}
```

Edit:

I can do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

if [[ -z "$(type -t unzip)" ]]; then
  echo "Missing dep unzip"
  exit 1
fi

@test ...
```

And that works fine for checks to be run at the beginning of a test, except that it doesn't output as part of the report.

But if I want to determine if a sourced script correctly defined a function and bail if it's not, adding that kind of test prevents any kind of a report being generated. Successful tests are not displayed.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are asking, you want to know 3 things? 1. How to abort the remainder of a single test file 2. How to abort the remainder of all test files 3. How to output both the abort message as well as the other test output (i.e. successful tests). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

- To see the abort message, redirect the message in global scope to `stderr` using `>&2`.
- To abort *all* files after failure, use `exit 1` in global scope.
- To only abort a single file, create a `setup` function that uses `skip` to only abort the tests in that file.
- To fail tests in a single file, create a `setup` function that uses `return 1` to fail the tests in that file.

---

### The answer in more detail

#### Aborting *all* files

You were *almost* there with your second example. The trick is to redirect the output to `stderr`<sup>[1](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/wiki/Bats-Evaluation-Process)</sup>.

Using `exit` or `return 1` from the global scope will halt the entire test suite.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

if [[ -z "$(type -t unzip)" ]]; then
  echo "Missing dep unzip" >&2
  return 1
fi

@test ...
```

The drawback is that any tests in and after the aborted file will *not* be run, even if those tests were to pass.

#### Aborting a *single* file

A more fine-grained solution would be to add a `setup`<sup>[2](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#setup-and-teardown-pre--and-post-test-hooks)</sup> function that will `skip`<sup>[3](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#skip-easily-skip-tests)</sup> if the dependency is not present.

As the `setup` function is called before each test in the file it is defined in,
all tests in that file will be skipped if the dependency is missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup(){
    if [[ -z "$(type -t unzip)" ]]; then
        skip "Missing dep unzip"
    fi
}

@test ...
```

#### Failing rather than skipping

It is also possible to *fail* tests that have a unmet dependecy. Using `return 1`
from the a test's `setup` function will fail all tests in that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup(){
    if [[ -z "$(type -t unzip)" ]]; then
        echo "Missing dep unzip"
        return 1
    fi
}

@test ...
```

As the message output is not in global scope, it does not have to be redirected to `sdterr` (although that will work too).

### Footnotes

1. There is mention of this at the bottom of [the page about Bats-Evaluation-Process in the wiki](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/wiki/Bats-Evaluation-Process) and in the manual (if you run `man 7 bats`):

   ```
    CODE OUTSIDE OF TEST CASES

        You can include code in your test file outside of @test functions.
        For example, this may be  useful  if  you  want  to check for
        dependencies and fail immediately if they´re not present. However,
        any output that you print in code outside of @test, setup or teardown
        functions must be redirected to stderr (>&2). Otherwise, the output
        may cause Bats to fail by polluting the TAP stream on stdout.
   ```
2. For details on `setup` see https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#setup-and-teardown-pre--and-post-test-hooks
3. For details on `skip` see https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#skip-easily-skip-tests

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot.

Comment: A superb answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to always test if something critical failed in teardown, and use this to skip next tests in setup, like so:

file `${BATS_PARENT_TMPNAME}.skip` exists if "critical" test failed. It will contain the test name.

```
# Runs before each @test
setup() {
    ISCRITICAL=0
    if [ -f ${BATS_PARENT_TMPNAME}.skip ] ; then
        test_name=$(cat ${BATS_PARENT_TMPNAME}.skip)
        skip "skiped because critical test $test_name failed:"
    fi
...
}
```

Create `${BATS_PARENT_TMPNAME}.skip` if test failed and it had `ISCRITICAL=1`, so the rest can be skipped.

```
# Runs after each @test
teardown() {
    if [[ $ISCRITICAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        [ -n "$BATS_TEST_COMPLETED" ] || echo "$BATS_TEST_NAME" >  ${BATS_PARENT_TMPNAME}.skip # stop all testing if this fails
    fi

}
```

and the tests:

```
@test "Important dependency for testing exists" {
    ISCRITICAL=1 # skip all other tests if this fails
    #test content here
}

@test "another test" {
    #test content here
}
```

So in this way you just have to set ISCRITICAL=1 in the test cases you need to bail (e.g. dep test)

Comment: Interesting. I've done something similar, but I think yours is little more compact and doesn't pollute the test file itself quite as much.